# Is it stupid to calculate the mean of standard deviations

Tags: statistics

I have several point on a chromosome that I am getting measurements from. Each point is measured 15 times. I want to demonstrate that the standard deviation across the whole chromosome for each point, for this measurement, is very low. I also want to show the median, upper and lower quartile for teh standard deviations across the whole chromosome. Is it too simple to just get standard deviations for the 15 measurements at each point within a chromosome and then average them (and get medians etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are repeating your experiment 15 times...

Then you may get 15 different standard deviations for each experiment....

I think it won't be stupid to go for mean of standard deviation of 15 experiments in this case....